# How to make images rounded corner when uploading image with MiniMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rounded-corners, minimagick

Is it possible to make an image (avatar image uploaded by user) rounded corners for my Rails application?

I'm currently using MiniMagick with CarrierWave to upload and resize photos.

Comment: doesnt CSS do the trick?

Comment: How do you resize the image , please add your code . So that we can modify the way you want .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by uDaY, what about letting your image unchanged, and do everything in CSS? For cross-browser rounded corners, have a look maybe at [Bourbon](http://railscasts.com/episodes/330-better-sass-with-bourbon), recently covered in a railscasts episode.

Comment: That might be an option. I thought keeping the rounded image processing to server reduces the load on the client. Plus Bourbon doesn't seem to have Rounded Corners for images, just for divs

Comment: If you use the image as a background image in a div, and round the corners of the div with CSS, you end up with an image with rounder corners. For what reason so you want to reduce load on the client?